# How to take advantage of AngularJS $routeprovider resolve feature and keeps a good loading user experience

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I have read a few articles about the $routeprovider resolve feature. The main idea comes from this repo created by my favorite AngularJS developer Todd Motto. https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#controllers

```
// avoid
function MainCtrl (SomeService) {
  var _this = this;
  // unresolved
  _this.something;
  // resolved asynchronously
  SomeService.doSomething().then(function (response) {
    _this.something = response;
  });
}
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

// recommended
function config ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    resolve: {
      // resolve here
    }
  });
}
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(config);
```

I really like the way how route resolves all the controller dependencies first before loading the controller. It keeps the code very clean. However, if the resolve process takes a significant amount of time, the page will **stuck there with no visual feedback** until everything finishes loading.

Before I switched to use $routeprovider resolve, I used to put everything in the controller then create a async loading view directive. The directive will display a loading progress bar while all the $http requests are downloading data. I am wondering if there is a way to keep the visual feedback and also put all the resolve steps in the route provider.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it's no different from a static web site, where nothing happens until the response comes back from the server. The only difference is the native browser spinner feedback. I use an HTTP interceptor that makes a spinner icon visible if an AJAX request takes more than 500 millis. https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: You could also use router events to do the same thing.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, although using HTTP interceptor could solve the issue but I may not want to track all the http request. Todd's answer is more straightforward since it attacks the route change directly.
Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the resolves are kicking off, you can hook into `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess` events. These events you listen for and can show or hide ajax spinners/loading messages based on the event type.

[More here!](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: @zeroliu :P heyyyyyyyyyy! Hope this helped anyway, happy coding.